# How to make input[][] return a Just Int instead of String in Elm?

Tags: functional-programming, frontend, backend, elm

I'm a complete beginner to Elm an I'm struggling with types. I've been struggling a lot with types and I couldn't figure out a convenient way of fixing this problem. The piece of code in question is this:

```
view model =
    div []
        [ h1 [] [ text "Robot" ]
        , input [ onInput SetX, value model.x ] []
        , input [ onInput SetY, value model.y ] []
        , input [ type_ "Int" , onInput SetCommands, value model.x] []
        , button [ onClick ButtonPressed] []
        , input [ readonly True ] []
        ]
```

X and Y are Ints used in the following function:

```
execute_orders : Int -> Int -> String -> String -> String -> { x : Int, y : Int, dir : String }
execute_orders x y commands lang dir =
    let
        moves =
            case lang of
                "English" ->
                    "RLF"

                "French" ->
                    "HVG"

                "Swedish" ->
                    "DGT"

                _ ->
                    Debug.todo "No Language Found"

        fw =
            right 1 moves

        directions =
            facing dir

        rght =
            left 1 moves

        lft =
            slice 1 2 moves

        first_move =
            left 1 (toUpper commands)

        rest =
            slice 1 (length commands) (toUpper commands)
    in
    if first_move == "" then
        { x = x, y = y, dir = fromJust (head directions) }

    else if first_move == fw then
        if dir == "N" then
            execute_orders x (y - 1) rest lang dir

        else if dir == "E" then
            execute_orders (x + 1) y rest lang dir

        else if dir == "S" then
            execute_orders x (y + 1) rest lang dir

        else
            execute_orders (x - 1) y rest lang dir

    else if first_move == lft then
        execute_orders x y rest lang (fromJust (head (turn_left directions)))

    else if first_move == rght then
        execute_orders x y rest lang (fromJust (head (turn_right directions)))

    else
        Debug.todo "branch '_' not implemented"
```

I need x and y to be Int's but casting them from String results in the Maybe Integer type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to simply "cast" a `String` to an `Int` because there's no total mapping in that direction. There is, for example, no obvious integer representation for the string `"banana"`. What you are struggling with isn't "types", but different things being different for different reasons, and having to make a decision to consolidate those differences.

[`String.toInt`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/String#toInt) returns a `Maybe Int` because it's up to you to decide what to do when there's no reasonable and obvious integer representation for a given string. It's your choice whether you want to just default to `0`, `-1`, or perhaps display the string `-` instead. These are all reasonable choices for different scenarios, but since `String.toInt` can't possibly know which scenario you're in, **you** have to make that decision.

If you simply want to fall back to a default integer, or you're certain that any given string will have a valid integer representation, you can use [`Maybe.withDefault`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Maybe#withDefault):

```
String.toInt "42" |> Maybe.withDefault 0     -- 42
String.toInt "banana" |> Maybe.withDefault 0 -- 0
```

Or you can use a `case` expression to do something completely different:

```
case String.toInt s of
  Just n ->
    span [] [ text (n + 1 |> String.fromInt) ]

  Nothing ->
    button [ onClick ... ] [ text "-" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the HTML input event always deals with strings, you need to parse the string you receive at some point. There are three options that I see.

First, the payload of your event message can be a `String`, and then you parse that string in your `update` function.

```
type Msg
    = SetX String

type alias Model =
    { x : Int }

update msg model =
    case msg of
        SetX xString ->
            case String.toInt xString of
                Nothing ->
                    model
                Just x ->
                    { model | x = x }
```

A variation of the above would be to store `x` as a `Maybe String` on your model if that makes sense, and/or storing some value for tracking an error state if you want to show a message when an invalid value is sent. This is the simplest and most flexible approach.

A second option is to have the payload of your event message be a `Maybe Int`. [`Html.Events.onInput`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/1.0.0/Html-Events#onInput) is a function which takes a "tagger" function which accepts a `String` and outputs a message. While you can just give a message constructor that takes a `String` payload, you can also give a function which does some processing before creating a `Msg` value.

```
type Msg
    = SetY (Maybe Int)

view model =
    input [ type_ "number", onInput (\value -> String.toInt value |> SetY) ] []
```

The third option is to have the payload of your event message be an `Int`. This will require you to create your own version of `onInput` using [`Html.Events.on`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/1.0.0/Html-Events#on). `on` takes a `Json.Decode.Decoder msg` instead of the `(String -> msg)` function that `onInput` takes. The message will only be produced if the decoder succeeds; that is, events which produce a failed decoder will be ignored. This allows you to handle the case where the parsing fails within the event handler.

```
type Msg
    = SetY Int

view model =
    input [ type_ "number", onNumericInput SetY ] []

-- based on https://github.com/elm/html/blob/97f28cb847d816a6684bca3eba21e7dbd705ec4c/src/Html/Events.elm#L115-L122
onNumericInput : (Int -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onNumericInput toMsg =
    let
        alwaysStop : a -> ( a, Bool )
        alwaysStop x =
            ( x, True )

        failIfNothing : Maybe a -> Decode.Decoder a
        failIfNothing maybe =
            case maybe of
                Nothing ->
                    Decode.fail "Parsing failed"

                Just a ->
                    Decode.succeed a

        decoder : Decode.Decoder msg
        decoder =
            Events.targetValue
                |> Decode.map String.toInt
                |> Decode.andThen failIfNothing
                |> Decode.map toMsg
    in
    Events.stopPropagationOn "input" (decoder |> Decode.map alwaysStop)
```

You can see the last two options in a full example at https://ellie-app.com/h6fstFTyjXDa1